# Multiple calls to bypass vibrate

Tags: calls

In iOS there's an option to make the phone ring even if it is set to silent mode when the same number calls consecutively.  Is there an equivalent option in Android?

Comment: Android added "Allow Repeat Callers" feature recently, in Pie I think.

Comment: do you know where they put the setting?

Comment: Settings > Sound > Do Not Disturb > Calls > Allow repeat callers